# Converting native int to Jbyte Array

Tags: java, android, c++, arrays, java-native-interface

I have a JNI C++ function in which i want to convert a integer to jbyte array. I need to first put it in a native integer to make sure that to other side (a C++ client can read it)

The funciton looks as follows:

```
    JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_com_example_communicationmoduleTCPIP_communicationmoduleTCPIP_CalcSize(
    JNIEnv * env, jobject,
    jint Size){
    jbyteArray Array;

    int CSize = (int)Size;
    //char Buffer[4];

    //itoa(CSize, Buffer, 10);
    //snprintf(Buffer, 4,"%d",CSize);


            __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Tag", "==== 1 ");

            // Init  java byte array
            Array = env->NewByteArray(4);

            __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Tag", "==== 2 ");


            // Set byte array region with the size of the SendData CommStruct.
            // Now we can send the data back.
            env->SetByteArrayRegion(Array, 0, 4, (jbyte*)CSize);

            __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Tag", "==== 3 ");

            return Array;

}
```

The function lets the application crash at the setbyteArrayRegion, does anybody know how to properly convert a int to a byte array.

All suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`env->SetByteArrayRegion(Array, 0, 4, (jbyte*)CSize);`

What you are saying here is to take the value of CSize( lets say its 15 ) and assume that its the memory address of a jbyte value.  What you actually want is to give the starting address of the CSize variable.

`env->SetByteArrayRegion(Array, 0, 4, (void *)(&CSize));`

Comment: Thank you for your comment i tried your suggestion but it won't compile. I tried the following:env->SetByteArrayRegion(Array, 0, 4, (void*)(&CSize)); This gives the following errors: nvalid conversion from 'void*' to 'const jbyte* {aka signed char const*}' [-fpermissive]
C:/ndk/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:967:10: error:   initializing argument 4 of 'void _JNIEnv::SetByteArrayRegion(jbyteArray, jsize, jsize, const jbyte*)' [-fpermissive]
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/opencv1/HelperFunctions.o] Error 1 Any idea's?

Comment: Hi I solved it bij doing the following: env->SetByteArrayRegion(Array, 0, 4, (jbyte*)(&CSize)); Give the adress of the integer and then cast it to jbyte. Thank you for you help!